# how can I search for documents with a specific value in lucene and ravendb

Tags: lucene, ravendb

First off. I am having trouble finding documentation for how to use ravendb with lucene. I can't seem to find documentation to help me query ravendb in the raven studio. Can anyone point men int he right direction?

So if I have the following document:

```
{
    "Name": "My Name",
    "object": {
        "ObjectName": "Name of an object"
    },
    "array": [
        {
            "first": "first element"
        },
        {
            "second": "second element"
        }
    ]
}
```

How can I query ravendb to find all documents that have a "first element" string for the "first" key?

If I do `array.count: 2`. That will return all documents that where array has a length of 2. However if I want to find arrays where the array has greater than say 4 elements, `array.count > 4` does not work.

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Again, can you point me to this elusive documentation. I must be searching for the wrong thing.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query syntax is documented here:
https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/3.5/csharp/indexes/querying/full-query-syntax

The query you want is:

```
array,first: "first element"
```

The comma operation in RavenDB 3.5 is used to nest into an array.

For range queries, you'll need:

```
 array.Count_Range: [Ix4 TO *]
```

Comment: I was wondering what Ix was but you already answered that too. Cheers Buddy.     https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32101801/lucene-net-range-subquery-not-returning-expected-results-ravendb-related